# AVRO schema for undefined map field

Tags: avro

I want to define an AVRO schema for a message queue which contains a field without a fixed content. The only limitation I want to apply is it needs to be a dictionary / map, but it can contain any value type inside.

I've tried with the following:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "namespace": "CDCEvent",
  "name": "CDCEvent",
  "fields": [
    {
      "doc": "The system that generated the event",
      "type": "string",
      "name": "sys"
    },
    {
      "doc": "The operation performed on the event",
      "type": "string",
      "name": "op"
    },
    {
      "doc": "The payload of the event",
      "type": {
        "type": "map",
        "values": "string"
      },
      "name": "payload"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, this enforces the values in the field to be strings, which is not what I need. Is it possible to define this on AVRO, or does it cancel the purpose of AVRO schemas?

Note: I've tried defining the `payload` field as a string, but that doesn't fit my use case.